# RewriteRule for .htaccess file not working

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a requirement where I need to redirect users like below :
"www.example.com/text1?a=1&b=2" to "www.example.com/text2?a=1&b=2&c=3"

For this, in my .htaccess file I am using the below mod-rewrite rule as :

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /text1(.*) www.example.com/**text2?c=3 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Have also tried :

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteRule /text1(.*) www.example.com/**text2$1&c=3
```

However, the above is not working for me and if I attempt to go to "www.example.com/text1?a=1&b=2", I get a straight 404.

Could someone please advise?

Thank you much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following, its mostly a internal redirect so we need not to have `R=301` in here.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^text1/?$ /text2?%{QUERY_STRING}&c=3 [NC,NE,L]
```

OR as per anubhava sir's comments you could try following. I will discuss with him more in morning about my above one as it's late night here

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteRule ^text1/?$ /text2?c=3 [NC,QSA,L]
```

***Explanation:***

`RewriteEngine ON`: Making RewriteEngine `ON` so that rules MOD rewrite rules are allowed to be written in apache(.htaccess file).

`RewriteRule`:

- `^text1/?$` On left hand side checking if URI starts from `text1` and with optional `/` then go to right side of this rule and redirect.
- `/text2?%{QUERY_STRING}&c=3 [NC,NE,L]`: Creating new value of uri here, it starts from `text2` then `%{QUERY_STRING}` is default variable which has value of your already passed query string(after `?`) `a=1&b=2` so it adds that old uri's query string, then `&c=3` adds new value to this URI here. NOw coming to flags `NC,NE,L`, `L` means for this condition its last rule, `NC` means ignore case applied in URI(left hand side) and `NE` to NOT to convert values(which you were getting `%26` in your comments).

Comment: so that partially works. If I do that, my result string is :   ***/text2?a=1&b=2%26c=3.       So you see that '%26' before c=3? That makes the url incorrect.

Comment: @MagicStar, could you please try updated rule once? Please make sure you clear your cache of browser before testing it.

Comment: perfect that makes it crystal clear for me, thank you again! :)

Comment: @MagicStar, your welcome, keep doing Q & A on this great site cheers

Comment: It should be: `RewriteRule ^text1/?$ /text2?c=3 [NC,QSA,L]` otherwise `/text1` will become `/text2&c=3` making it invalid URI

Comment: @anubhava, thank you sir for letting now. But sir it's not having the query string part no from passed URL(OR shall I add condition to check if QUERY_STRING is NOT NULL here)? That's why I went with this approach I tested it too. By seeing OP's URLs it looked good, kindly enlighten me in case I am missing something thank you

Comment: A quick follow up on this @RavinderSingh13, above queries work perfectly for my local domain. But as soon as I deploy them to a server (dev/qa etc), the above queries with relative urls won't work anymore. Which means I have to provide the full absolute URL for it to work. For eg, instead of '/text2?c=3 [NC,QSA,L] ', I have to write 'https://*****/text2?c=3 [NC,QSA,L] '.      Would you know why this could be happening

Comment: @anubhava please look up the above follow up, when you get a chance

Comment: What `'https://*****/text2?c=3 [NC,QSA,L]` is rewrite rule? No way it will ever work. We never match any URL in rules like that.

Comment: Fixed the above, needed to add the R flag to make it work across.